# Count number of spans till span with a specific id

Tags: jquery

how can I count the number of span-s till the span with a specific id.

for example:

till span with id="a5" is the **6th** span.

```
<table border="3">
    <tr>
        <td><span id="a2" class="arrow_icon a6" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a1" class="arrow_icon a1" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a3" class="arrow_icon a11" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a4" class="arrow_icon a16" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a6" class="arrow_icon a2" isClicked="0"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="a5" class="arrow_icon a21" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a7" class="arrow_icon a7" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a8" class="arrow_icon a12" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a9" class="arrow_icon a17" isClicked="0"></span></td>
        <td><span id="a10" class="arrow_icon a22" isClicked="0"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried something like:

```
var count = 0;
$("span:first").nextUntil("#a5").andSelf().each(function(index) {
     count++;
});
alert(count); // should alert '6'
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your initial selection contains **only one** span element in the first `<td>...</td>`. So you should change it to rather `$("span")...`.

Second of all, *nextUntil* function searches amongst the **siblings** of the selected items, just look at the jQuery docs to confirm that:

[nextUntil specification](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

That means, that your collection of spans changes to ... zero. Why? Their direct parents are the `<td>...</td>` tags, which contain only one span, so **none** of them actually have any siblings.

The remedy is quite simple:

```
var count = 0;

$("span").each(function(i, e){
    if(!$(this).is("#a5"))
        count++; //count it up
    else
        return false; //exit the each function
});

alert(count); //alerts '5', as it should
```

The main reason it works is because the selection is already sorted the way they are presented in a DOM. Otherwise it would be quite hard to do anything with it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) because that looks at siblings, and not all the span elements in your example are siblings. Putting a selector into `$(...)` should produce a jQuery object that respect's the element's order in the DOM so maybe just:

```
var count = 0;
$("span").each(function(i) {
    count++;
    if (this.id === "a5") {return false;} // breaks out of loop when the id is found
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through all the spans with `.each()`, and use the index (number of loop iterations) as counter:

```
var c;
$("span").each(function(index, element) {
    if(element.id == "a5") {
        c = index; // set counter to current index value
        return false; // break the each loop
    }
});
alert(c);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rPcN/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use nextUntil() because they're not siblings. This is the best way I can think of.

```
var a5index;
$('table span').each(function(idx){
  if( $(this).is('#a5')){
    a5Index = idx;
    return true; // No reason to keep going after we find it...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return false to get out of the .each loop early

```
var count = 0;
var toId = "a5";
$("span").each(function(){
   count++;
   if(this.id == toId) {
      return false;
   }
});
console.log(count);
```

or use a single line using [.index](http://api.jquery.com/index)

```
console.log( $("span").index($("#a5")) );
```

Comment: putting `this` into `$(...)` just so you can get the id attribute is a bit of a waste. Just use `this.id`

Comment: yea was doing something else with it and needed wrapped and just didnt think to unwrap it.